# Can a smart contract approval token of wallet address to a spender?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20

For example, if wallet A calls a method of contract B, and this method authorizes Token X  from wallet A to contract C, can the contract B do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-approve-address-uint256-

Answer (score 1):

No, as `approve` method sets the approvance for caller balance, that's why if the `B` contract calls the method, the approvance will be set for the `B` balance, not the `A` account. This is the standard and secure behaviour, that's why you send the approve transaction before swap.

Openzeppelin source - https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9e3f4d60c581010c4a3979480e07cc7752f124cc/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L142